# AWS Node 12 SDK V3 Deprecation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

Good Evening,

For some opening context. I am a mid level engineer at a company and I have a question about an upcoming AWS change as it relates to a Node Environment, and the SDK with it. I know I could be asking a fellow engineer or architect in my company however due todays market, we saw a severe cut in staff as well as some shake ups within the organization where I felt the better answer could come from colleagues here.

On [March 31, 2023 AWS has announced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-end-of-support-for-node-js-12-x-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3/) it will begin Phase 1 deprecation of support for Node 12 on AWS SDK V3.

In the attached document they linked, that describes their [runtime policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html#runtime-support-policy), I see they are specifying the AWS SDK 2.1055.0

```
Name - Identifier - SDK - OS - Architecture - Deprecation (Phase 1)

Node.js 12 - nodejs12.x - 2.1055.0 - Amazon Linux 2 - x86_64, arm64 - Mar 31, 2023
```

Our backend, is the following

```
runtime: nodejs12.x // serverless


AWS SDK: ^2.1021.0 // pkg.json
```

Can I have a second opinion around my fears that my stack will be in the category of those affected by this change in the coming days? i.e. We would be entering phase 1 on March 31st?

Comment: I see you using SDK V2 which they say isn't included.   Node 12 has been EOL for almost a year though so you should get on something newer anyway.

Comment: Right, they mention that SDK in the announcement article, but they specified a different SDK in the runtime policy docs, which is my confusion here. And I agree on the Node 12.

Comment: You're conflating 2 different things.  The announcement you linked refers to ending support for Node 12 in SDK V3.  Separately, Node 12 Lambda runtime is going into Phase 1 deprecation at the end of the month which means you can't create new lambdas with it anymore.